# Python Unicode - What Characters Can Be Printed in Windows Console?

Tags: python, windows, unicode, surrogate-pairs

Which Unicode characters can be printed in a Windows console from Python?

The following code

```
for code in range(1114112):
    print(chr(code), end=",")
```

gives unimpressive results, including an error:

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\ud800' in position 0: surrogates not allowed`

Yet the docs for `str` claim values up to `0x110000` are allowed.

Is there a way to get some more characters to display?

Comment: `\ud800` is a [surrogate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U+D800_to_U+DFFF) so is not printable

Comment: The answer will crucially depend on how your Windows is configured. Many systems are set up so that only a single legacy code page is supported out of the box (in particular, older versions of Windows).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question, we need to check several layers of Unicode.

Valid Unicode code points are from 0 to U+10FFFF. You may find with `unicodedata.category(char)` what category has a Unicode code point.

The values from U+D800 to U+DFFF are surrogates, they should not be used (and they cannot be encoded/decoded in UTF-16). [They are used to enhance UCS-2 (so old Unicode, which has code point until U+FFFF), to UTF-16 (to U+10FFFF). Old programs/languages (as Javascript) may use two surrogates representation, instead of one UTF-16 codepoint].

Note: Python allows them because of *surrogateescape* (mostly used to read sys.argv), but you should ignore them, but use them only internally, before to convert them properly.

So, do no try to use such codes.

There are also the **noncharacters**: U+FDD0–U+FDEF, and FFFE or FFFF (i.e., U+FFFE, U+FFFF, U+1FFFE, U+1FFFF, … U+10FFFE, U+10FFFF) [from [Wikipedia, Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#General_Category_property)], which should not be used, but ev. BOM (U+FEFF), but in this case only as first character.  Reason: the first block: [What's the purpose of the noncharacters U+FDD0 to U+FDEF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188679/whats-the-purpose-of-the-noncharacters-ufdd0-to-ufdef), the others: to autodetect encoding, so we should not have *confusing* code points: if you detect them, you know that you are using a wrong encoding, and you change encoding, until you get a valid first code point.

Now, with the `unicodedata.category(char)`, you can get also the categories of the code (see [Unicode character categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property#General_Category)).  Characters until U+1F, and U+7F–U+9F are control character, do no print them.

You may have formatting characters, which could modify nearby characters.

So you may want to exclude the `C*` (note: this will discard all the above characters) and maybe also the `Z*` (white spaces) character categories.

So you have the printable characters, known by `unicodedata` standard module. Use `unicodedata.unidata_version` to check up which unicode version the database is updated. You may ev. allow `Cn` category (unassigned): maybe now they are assigned.

But this is not enough. You need a font to display such characters. Google has the ["No Tofu fonts"](https://www.google.com/get/noto/) which is (I think) the most complete font.

But this is also not enough. You get only the standard representation of the characters (and probably not, you should add a U+200C (ZWNJ) after each character, to force fonts not to join characters (e.g. in the Indic languages). But so you miss all the characters which are represented by a combination of code points: e.g. many accented characters, characters enclosed in circles or squares, country flags (you need two country code characters in the correct order), etc.

Note: I'm curious on how to get all glyphs from a font file, but this is not your question.

ADDENDUM:

I forgot to say: Combining characters cannot be displayed alone, so you need to precede the e.g. with U+25CC, you may check them with `unicodedata.combining(chr)`.

So you may use this code

```
# if your console is not UTF-8 (or any unicode encoding) and python
# do no get it, you will get garbage
import unicodedata

combining = '\u25cc'
placeholder = '\ufffd'
zwnj = '\u200c'

line = ''
for code in range(0x10FFFF+1):
    c = chr(code)
    cat = unicodedata.category(c)
    if cat.startswith('C'):  # and cat != 'Cn':
        r = placeholder
    elif cat.startswith('Z'):
        r = ' '
    elif unicodedata.combining(c) > 0:
        r = combining + c + zwnj
    else:
        r = c + zwnj
    line += r
    if code % 256 == 255:
        print(line)
        line = ''
```

Comment: The classic Windows console can only render codes from the basic multilingual plane (i.e. codes below 65536) because a text 'cell' stores a UCS-2 16-bit character code instead of UTF-16. It also doesn't support font fallback, so it's limited to the glyphs that are directly supported by the selected font. Complex scripts and combining codes are also not supported.